# How to compare database values with forms.py value in django

Tags: django

How to compare database reseved_start_time value with forms.py reserved_start_time form value.

models.py

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    Power_System = 0
    Water_System = 1
    Blade = 2

    STATUS = (
        (Power_System, _("Power System")),
        (Water_System, _("Water System")),
        (Blade, _("Blade Server")),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey("auth.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    reserved_start_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    reserved_start_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    reserved_end_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=Power_System)
    updated_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.reserved_start_date)
```

---

if reserved_start_time section return "Try the another starting time" message when database values dont have any time which write in the form screen.

forms.py

```
class ReservationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        fields = ["username","lastname","email","reserved_start_date","reserved_start_time","reserved_end_time","status"]
    def clean(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
        lastname = self.cleaned_data.get("lastname")
        email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        reserved_start_time = self.cleaned_data.get("reserved_start_time")
        reserved_end_time = self.cleaned_data.get("reserved_end_time")

        if not username:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Adınızı Giriniz")
        if not lastname:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Soyadınızı Giriniz")
        if not email:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Email Adresini Giriniz")
        if not reserved_start_time:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Başlangıç Saatinizi Giriniz")
        if not reserved_end_time:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Son Saatinizi Giriniz")
        if email:
            validator = EmailValidator("^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$")
            validator(email)

        if reserved_start_time:
            rezersvasyon_zamani = Reservation.objects.get(reserved_start_time=reserved_start_time)
            for reservasyon in rezersvasyon_zamani:
                if reservasyon.reserved_start_time not in reserved_start_time:
                    raise forms.ValidationError("Try the another starting time")



        values = {
            "username": username,
            "lastname": lastname,
            "email": email,
            "reserved_start_time": reserved_start_time,
            "reserved_end_time": reserved_end_time,
        }
        return values
```

Answer (score 0):

you can you `self.instance` to get db values of saving objects

```
db_value_reserved_start_time  = self.instance.reserved_start_time 
reserved_start_time = self.cleaned_data.get("reserved_start_time")
```

and then you can compare it with values in form or do what you need

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super.clean()
    username = cleaned_data.get("username")
    lastname = cleaned_data.get("lastname")
    email = cleaned_data.get("email")
    reserved_start_time = cleaned_data.get("reserved_start_time")
    reserved_end_time = cleaned_data.get("reserved_end_time")
    db_value_reserved_start_time  = self.instance.reserved_start_time 
    if db_value_reserved_start_time != reserved_start_time:
        # process your code when value stored in db differs from user input

    # ... your other code in clean() method
    return cleaned_data
```

Comment: I am tring this recommend. But I want to understand what does this self.instance.reserved_start_time return? queyset or something like that. Why ı ask that it returnes queryset , ı parse the value.

Comment: you can read about it in official docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method

Comment: I am trying but the code is not working or the code produce error. how to use the db_value_reserved_start_time to compare reserved_start_time. I want to do in form if ı write reserved_start_time, the code control the database which dont have writing reserved_start_time

Comment: i modified answer. added code for your `clean()` method, don't forget in other code to replace `self.cleaned_data` to `cleaned_data` in `clean()`

Comment: your stutiation did not work. Becouse db_value_reserved_start_time  return none value so ı dont compare them

Comment: if it's None, then there is no value stored in database

Comment: ı took value with using Model Name.objects.values("what ı want to take") and ı parse the value and compare the parsing value and form value